# Manually running rsnapshot

Tags: backup, rsync, testing

this is my first post here. I have configured rsnapshot for backing up remote hosts. Some of them are working fine and for some of them in the morning, I am  having email with some error code 255. I want to run rsnapshot only for these problematic hosts. So that I can troubleshoot the problem. Any idea how to test or manually run snapshot to test configuration running fine. Please remember that I am not asking for snapshot syntax checking.

Comment: There might be logs configured on your (local) rsnapshot server. Check them. Maybe somewhere in /var/log/rsnapshot/...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `rsnapshot -t daily` and you will see the single `rsync` commands to be issued to the remote hosts. Run these `rsync` commands in dry-run (`-n` option) to see what happens.

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo rsnapshot daily
```

Will run a daily snapshot for you.  Replacing daily with weekly or monthly will also do what you want.  Also when running interactively I like to run with `-v` so you can have some idea of progress.

Comment: Depending on the configuration, that might be `sudo rsnapshot alpha`, if rsnapshot is using the "abstract" backup names, rather than the hourly/daily/...

Comment: Yeah that's correct. You can look for the retain keyword in your rsnapshot configuration (/etc/rsnapshot.conf) to determine what your backup stages are named.

Comment: Upvote since it answers to "how to run .." not "how to test ..."

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer. Actually there is no rsnapshot command to run manually rather its all about rsync. Since rsnapshot works based on rsync so almost all command are in rsync. So while I tried a dry run, it was showing me what rsync command will be executed during snapshot backup. I tried this rsync command and it was enough for me. Thanks

Comment: Wrong. There is an rsnapshot command to run and you should use that. It's way safer as it does mount tests etc. Today I use "sudo rsnapshot alpha"